# Valid generic code to index 2D or 1D masked arrays into 1D arrays in Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, dimensions

I would like to have a valid code for either 2D or 1D masked array to extract a 1D array from it. In the 2D case, one column would be entirely masked and should be removed (this can be done as shown [in this question for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19380996/remove-columns-where-every-value-is-masked)).

```
import numpy as np

a = np.ma.masked_array(range(10*2), mask=[True, False]*10).reshape(10,2)
a = np.ma.masked_equal(a, 13)
b = np.ma.masked_equal(np.array(range(10)), 3)

print(a)
print(b)
# [[-- 1]
#  [-- 3]
#  [-- 5]
#  [-- 7]
#  [-- 9]
#  [-- 11]
#  [-- --]
#  [-- 15]
#  [-- 17]
#  [-- 19]]
# [0 1 2 -- 4 5 6 7 8 9]

# HERE I would like the same indexing valid for both (2D and 1D) situations:
a = a[:, ~np.all(a.mask, axis=0)].squeeze()
b = b[:] # I am not supposed to know that b is actually 1D and not a problematic 2D array

print(a)
print(b)
# [1 3 5 7 9 11 -- 15 17 19]
# [0 1 2 -- 4 5 6 7 8 9]
print(a-b)
# [1 2 3 -- 5 6 -- 8 9 10]
```

What would be a valid, pythonic code to achieve this?

Sub-question: to my surprise, during my attempts the following did work:

```
b = b[:, ~np.all(b.mask, axis=0)].squeeze()
print(b)
# [1 3 5 7 9 11 -- 15 17 19]
```

Why don't I get a `IndexError: too many indices for array` error while I use 2D indexing for this 1D array?

Is there any better option to address the original question? Thanks!

Comment: b can be treated the same way as a - what's wrong with `b[:, ~np.all(b.mask, axis=0)].squeeze()`?

Comment: This is ironic - I just removed the 2d part of my question (thinking it would blur things too much - I've put it back, then). So indeed I agree with you, this would work, though I don't really get why this doesn't throw an `IndexError`. And besides, it means this would be a good way to proceed then? (I was expecting other, better/smarter solutions with fancy indexing, new axis creation, etc.)

Comment: where do you think you use 2D indexing? A 1D array also has an axis '0'.

Comment: I guess because of the `[... ,...]` which lets me think that I am indexing on all rows `:` and then on some columns `~np.all()`... If this is an appropriate way to do it and no other (better?) pops out, then probably the best is to develop your comment (perhaps addressing my confusion?) as an answer I'd accept? (if we can't make it useful, then I'd delete the question not to pollute SO). Thanks anyway!

Comment: or sorry, my bad - now I see your point, but I don't have a good explanation why it works as it works, so leave the question here, I'll think about it or maybe someone else can clarify it with links to the pertaining documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `a = a[:, ~np.all(a.mask, axis=0)].squeeze()` for both cases (1D and 2D).

In the 1D case of your example you get `b[:, ~np.all(b.mask, axis=0)]` which is `b[:, True]`. It seems that this should throw an indexing error but `True` behaves like `np.newaxis` in this case, i.e. the result of `b[:, True]` is an array of shape `(10,1)`. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45493750/3944322) for why this is so and what's the motivation behind it (the answer pertains to the 0-dimensionsal case but it turns out to work for higher dimensions the same way). `squeeze` then removes this additional dimension so that you didn't notice it.